# How do I style three divs as two columns with either flex or css-grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

### Goal

I want two divs (title and description) in column 1 with one div (button) in column 2 (see [Layout Goal](https://codepen.io/u1138/pen/MWxQxEN) for a visual example using table markup). The button should be vertically aligned to the center of the first column if that column grows taller than column 2. I only want to use CSS to create the layout--either css-grid or flexbox, and I do not want to inherit any of the grid styling from the outer grid.

### What I Have Tried

I have tried a variety of css-grid and flex layouts, and none of them worked. I could not figure out flexbox because I could never find a layout that was similar to my end goal, but it felt like it may be what I need. The closest I was able to get was using css-grid, but the second column would either grow (grid-row: 1/3) too much, making the whole column the button, or the button would not center vertically.

### Samples

- Target Code: https://codepen.io/u1138/pen/JjzpzMb
- Layout Goal (using a table): https://codepen.io/u1138/pen/MWxQxEN

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 24px;
  row-gap: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}


/* flex/grid properties */

.container {

}

.title,
.description {

}

.button {

}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to add some form of layout method to the `container`. `grid` is not inherited.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I intentionally left that blank because I had already tried flex and grid layouts that would not work and wanted suggestions on what that code should be. I do not want to inherit anything from the outer grid.

Comment: "I want it to look like a table. Here's the layout as I want it, using a table. " - Then, why don't you just use a table? ;-) Don't spend to much time on engineering stuff to look like a table, when you simply could use one. No one will check your source and say: "Haha, look, he used a table!"

Comment: @dognose: I cannot use a table because 1) I do not want to and should not for layout; and 2) I cannot change the markup of what I am styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those finding this question and wanting an answer, here is the solution using CSS grid layout by defining template areas.

### CSS to Add

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(100%);
  grid-template-areas:
    "title button"
    "description button";
  column-gap: 24px;

  /* center grid content top-to-bottom */
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;  
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
}

.button {
  grid-area: button;
  align-self: center;
}
```

### Solution Demo

I tossed in an "even-height" solution as well for good measure. This makes all boxes across all rows the same height. This add-on is applied to the parent container (`.outer-grid`).

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 24px;
  row-gap: 24px;

  /* makes height even across all rows */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.container {
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}


/* grid layout */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(100%);
  grid-template-areas:
    "title button"
    "description button";
  column-gap: 24px;

  /* center grid content top-to-bottom */
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;  
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
}

.button {
  grid-area: button;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element with a bit longer of a sentence so that it wraps.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element with an even longer, more complex sentence--one that should be more interesting but is not.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">Short description.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This could be Lorem Ipsum filler text, but why use filler text when you can write your own?</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">Which of the 118 elements is this? Specificity is key--whether in CSS or language.</div>
    <a class="button">Clarify</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">It's the end of the examples as we know it, and I feel fine.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to wrap a div around the text content and use flex, if you ask me.

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 24px;
  row-gap: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.button {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}


/* flex properties */

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.container .text-content {
  flex: auto;
}
.container .button {
  flex: none;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-content">
      <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
      <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    </div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-content">
      <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
      <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    </div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you can't change the markup, it should still be possible with `grid` as well

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 24px;
  row-gap: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.button {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}


/* grid properties */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0 1em;
}

.container .button {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @DustinComp. This is the closest yet! Is there any way to do this with without adding the div? I cannot change the markup. I guess that's where I am with trying to find a solution with either flexbox or css-grid.

Comment: @user1138 I added a solution using flex-grid that doesn't require markup changes

Answer (score -1):

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 24px;
  row-gap: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}


/* flex/grid properties */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.title,
.description {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.button {
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Title of Element</div>
    <div class="description">This is the description of the element.</div>
    <a class="button">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Igor. I have tried an approach like this, but its only drawbacks is that title and description are not collapsed (title fills out the space vertically to match the vertical size of the button). And the button is not vertically aligned in the center to both title and description.

Comment: Answers should have some explanation of the solution. See [answer].